# wxWidgets multi layer transparency-enabled drawing

Tags: wxwidgets

I am using wxWidgets to design a GUI that draws multiple layers **with transparency** on top of each other.
Therefore I have one method for each layer that draws with `wxGraphicsContext` onto the "shared" `wxImage`, which is then plotted to the `wxWindow` in the `paintEvent` method.

I have the layer data in arrays exactly of the same dimension as my `wxImage` and therefore I need to draw/manipulate pixel-wise, of course. Currently I am doing that with the `drawRectangle`-routine. My guess is that this is quite inefficient.

Is there a clever way to manipulate `wxImage`'s pixel data directly, enabling me to still use transparency of each separate layer in the resulting image? Or is the 1x1 pixel drawing with `drawRectangle` sufficient?

Thanks for any thoughts on this!

Comment: It's not really clear what is `drawRectangle()`. Also, do you use `wxGraphicsContext::Create(wxImage&)` or how do you draw on your image?

Comment: yes that's right, I use exactly that function `wxGraphicsContext::Create(wxImage&)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can efficiently manipulate `wxImage` pixels by just directly accessing them, they are stored in two contiguous RGB and alpha arrays which you can work with directly.

The problem is usually converting this `wxImage` to `wxBitmap` which can be displayed -- this is the expensive operation, and to avoid it raw bitmap access can be used to manipulate `wxBitmap` directly instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have thought exactly about that pixel data accessing, but don't know how to calculate the rgb and alpha manually for a pixel that I draw several layers upon. Is that easy to comprehend?

Comment: In general it's not that simple, of course, but some operations can be easily defined on individual pixels. I really don't understand what you are doing to say more, sorry. The point is that either you work with pixels directly using `wxImage::GetData()` or you draw on it using `wxGraphicsContext`, depending on what suits you more.